# Problem with Registration for SP:s Workflow 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, workflow, installation

Goal:
Install SP Workflow 2013 in my SharePoint 2013

Problem:
I have followed a guide line (http://tech.just4sharing.com/Pages/tech/Configuring-SharePoint-2013-to-support-workflow-Management-Service.aspx#.UwDhCbQ6tnE) and now I'm stuck in the message

```
Step 23:  Give this command "Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite
"http://xxxx" -WorkflowHostUri "http://xxxx:12291" - AllowOAuthHttp
```

The problem is that the PowerShell:s sourcecode

```
"Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite "http://sharepoint01" -WorkflowHostUri "http://sharepoint01:12290/" -AllowOAuthHttp"
```

do not work properly due to error message:

```
Register-SPWorkflowService : The term 'Register-SPWorkflowService' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, sc
ript file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct
 and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite "http://sharepoint01" -WorkflowHostUri "http: ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Register-SPWorkflowService:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

> What should I do in order to complete step 23?

Information:
I'm using SharePoint 2013.

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

Here's the command that worked for my environment where my SharePoint URL is http://sp.apple.com and the Web Front End server is named sharepointwfe. Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite "http://sp.apple.com" -WorkflowHostUri "http://sharepointwfe:12291" -AllowOAuthHttp

---

Comment: You are using SharePoint Server 2013 right? The 2013 Workflows (and the commandlets) are not available in SharePoint Foundation 2013.

Comment: I have installed workflow foundation or workflow manager that contain SP 2013 workflow

Comment: I have this same problem. I am running the SharePoint Command Shell and on the SPServer2013 server where Workflow Manager is installed. When I try to run the Register-SPWorkflowService cmdlet, I get the "Term is not recognized..." error.

Answer (score 3):

Run

```
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
```

before your line to load the SharePoint commandlets. Or use the SharePoint Management Shell

Comment: Unfortunatley I retrieve a new error message that is: "PS C:\Users\Administrator> Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite "http://sharepoint01/" -WorkflowHostUri "http://sharepoint01.ADVENTUREWORKS.com:12291" -AllowOAuthHttp
Register-SPWorkflowService : Unable to connect to the remote service at http://sharepoint01.adventureworks.com:12291/SharePoint/. See InnerExce
ption for more details. Client ActivityId : 4dc0a002-8338-452d-a240-2635ce547ac8. I have uploaded a new picture above. What is the next phase to do?

Comment: Are you executing this from an SP Server, because the error indicates that the site is remote from the machine executing the script. And, make sure the URLs are correct

Comment: 1."Are you executing this from an SP Server", Everything take place inside of WMware player. How I make a conformation if the site is remote from a machine executing the script?

Answer (score 1):

It is because you use SharePoint powershell in `Windows Powershell` console.

You should use `SharePoint 2013 Management Shell` console for running this script.

Or run `Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell` command in `Windows Powershell` console and you will be able to run any SharePoint powershell scripts.

Comment: So, what I said? ;)

Comment: you answered it faster than me ;)

Comment: Unfortunatley I retrieve a new error message that is: "PS C:\Users\Administrator> Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite "sharepoint01/"; -WorkflowHostUri "sharepoint01.ADVENTUREWORKS.com:12291"; -AllowOAuthHttp Register-SPWorkflowService : Unable to connect to the remote service at sharepoint01.adventureworks.com:12291/SharePoint. See InnerExce ption for more details. Client ActivityId : 4dc0a002-8338-452d-a240-2635ce547ac8. I have uploaded a new picture above. What is the next phase to do?

Comment: You can find correct Workflow Service address in `Internet Information Service Manager -> Sites -> Workflow Management Site` (on the right pane, in Browse Website section)

Comment: Please look at the picture above

Comment: try to use `http://adventureworks:12291/` url

Comment: "This page can't be displayed"

Answer (score -1):

Even i faced the same situation and it got cleared now. May be u got it fixed already but let me help you with the piece of information which i know.

First i was literally doubt about which cmd to run...there is cmd..powershell...management shell..etc  etc

Just make sure you run this command by opening "Sharepoint 2013 management shell"...right click and run as administrator.....then run the code.....it will work....

Answer (score -1):

SharePOint Foundation is not supported, therefor the cmdlet is not available